# Is heat treatment the only way to increase grain size in steel?

Tags: heat, metallurgy, crystallography

Heat treatment is a well-established method for increasing grain size in steel. Is there any other approach known to man? I cannot seem to find anything via web search.

Comment: Chemists are not the best group to ask this. Metallurgists may help, but not sure about it in this specific case. Both domains overlap just marginally  and chemists may have the needed experience rather incidentally.

Comment: Second possibility: physics.se, because the site maintains a dedicated tag `solid-state-physics` ([examples](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsolid-state-physics%5D+grain) of questions).

Comment: Could be helping.  But as SSP is a huge and complex domain of science, I cross my fingers for the artist.

Comment: The examples are already more specific to `grain` *within* the tag of `solid-state-physics`.  Some posts' titles about *grain size* ([examples](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsolid-state-physics%5D+grain+size)) are encouraging to address the question there. Though, how to overcome activation in a slab of metal without heat by fire, or radio (contactless zone melting with a high-frequency RF coil) ...

Comment: Okay I will try the physics forum -- thank you both for the pointer!

Comment: @artist_and_not_EE_by_training, high magnetic fields have been investigated for controlling grain size: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-materials-research/article/abs/effects-of-high-magnetic-field-on-austenite-formation-and-grain-size-in-a-hypereutectoid-carbon-steel/F7ADA09CCDF3B3C67D03A5D274765410 . But of course, that *still involved heat treatment*.